# Turn off firewall when developing in early stages with Symfony2?

Tags: authentication, authorization, symfony

Following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html) i'm developing a web application using symfony authentication/authorization architecture.

After designing the whole structure (routes, pages and security levels) i'm stuck: how can i develop my pages without enter credentials all the time? Is there any way to disable or turn off the entire firewall functionality? Should i use data fixtures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `app/config/security.yml` file, under the `firewalls` config option add or modify the `dev`...

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/
        security: false
```

Comment: What `dev` stand for? Environment?

Comment: dev = development environment

Comment: This firewall is just called "dev", it doesn't mean it just get's applied in dev environment.

Answer (score 3):

**The `security.firewalls.dev:` configuration is used in every Symfony environment (dev,test,prod)!**

**In Symfony 4**, to achieve disabling firewalls for all routes in just dev environment, you could do something like this:

**Setup:**

`config/packages/security.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN if the env var is not set.
    env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN): '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/'

security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: '%env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN)%'
            security: false
```

**Override per Symfony environment:**

create a new file `config/packages/dev/parameters.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN): '^/'
```

Now all routes are reachable without firewall in Symfony dev environ

**Override using environment variables:**

You could also override `SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN` in the `.env` file:

`SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN=^/`

This only works if you don't include the `.env` in your production environment, or if you specifically override the `SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN` environment variable there as well.