# Disable security firewall in test environment on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to disable a security firewall for a test environment in Symfony2, but i'm not having luck. Here's what i have in config_test.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        web:
            pattern: .*
            security: false
            anonymous: ~
```

However, this is not disabling security. Any ideas how i can completely disable security for a certain firewall when in test env?

Comment: You might also need to have an authenticated user in the system (I did).
Check my comment here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451969/authentication-in-functional-tests-in-symfony-2-1
Also check this one out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in similar topic [turn off firewall when developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174522/turn-off-firewall-when-developing-in-early-stages-with-symfony2) put following rule in Your security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/
        security: false
```

Answer (score 8):

**Do not change <kbd>security.yml</kbd>**, instead make an *ad hoc* rule for testing purposes.

You have to disable all the security firewalls configuration on your <kbd>config_test.yml</kbd>:

```
  imports:
      - { resource: config_dev.yml }

  framework:
      test: ~
      session:
          storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
      profiler:
          collect: false

  web_profiler:
      toolbar: false
      intercept_redirects: false

  swiftmailer:
      disable_delivery: true

  security:
      firewalls:
          dev:
              pattern:  ^/
              security: false
```

**Note**

Mind that `config_test.yml` imports `config_dev.yml`, which imports `config.yml`. So you must override all the basic configuration on test config file to make it works.

Answer (score 5):

### Possible solution

You could extract from `config.yml` this part of code:

```
imports:
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

And put it separately to `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml`. In this case `config_test.yml` will not import security configuration and, as result, you'll have no security in test environment.

Comment: Problem is: i'm using JMSSecurityExtraBundle with annotated security roles. I'm getting "The security context was not populated with a Token." all the time.

Comment: The solution from Valentas disables the firewall for prod too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch-off a particular firewall in a particular environment then the following solution may help.

In a Symfony 5.x app, I have an API that's usually protected by "basic" HTTP auth.  I wanted to switch-off authentication in the "test" environment.  Here's what my `security.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
when@test:
    security:
        firewalls:
            rest_api:
                security: false

security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        rest_api:
            pattern: ^/api/v\d+/
            provider: rest_api_users
            http_basic:
                realm: "REST API"
```

The important bit is at the top: the `when@test` bit.  It's pretty intuitive: that instruction starts a section in which you can override the 'default' config, defined elsewhere -- later on in the file in this case.  You can read about `when@` in https://symfony.com/doc/5.x/configuration.html#configuration-environments -- look for "You can also define options for different environments in a single configuration file using the special when keyword".